# Physical Activity and METS

Tags: exercise, metabolism, calculation, met

Suppose a person performs 3 horus of cardio at 9 METS. To obtain the same metabolic changes without exercise, would this require that the person wait 27 hours? Assume that the person's daily activity is at 1 MET.

In other words, to get the same metabolic changes as 3 hours of cardio at 9 METS, would the person who did no exercise have to wait 27 hours?

Comment: I actually do not see how it's a good idea to compare those two. Both burn the same amount of calories as indicated by their equal amount of METS. But one is 24h short (which would have to be spent at >=1 MET). Where did that day go and why is this still a valid comparison? (Honest question)

Answer (score 1):

If **waiting** = **watching television (1 MET)**, then yes, as per the [MET formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent):

**MET = vVO2Max = VO2 / 3.5 ~= KCal Burnt / (bodyMassKg * timeHours )**

So as you state:

**3 * 9 MET (cardio exercise) = 27 METS**

which is equivalent to:

**27 * 1 MET (watching TV) = 27 METS**

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Yes, you can get to the equivalent METS expenditure, but that's different (IMO, we'd need clarification from OP) than the metabolic changes of 3 hours of cardio. There is a large difference in 3 hours of cardio vs. 27 hours of watching TV.